# GTFS-realtime bindigns with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, symfony, dependencies, composer-php

I am having problem installing [Google GTFS-Realtime bindings](https://github.com/google/gtfs-realtime-bindings-php) library.

When running `composer require google/gtfs-realtime-bindings:^0.0.2`, I get the following error :

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for google/gtfs-realtime-bindings ^0.0.2 -> satisfiable by google/gtfs-realtime-bindings[0.0.2].
    - Conclusion: remove symfony/console v4.2.3
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/console v4.2.3
    - google/gtfs-realtime-bindings 0.0.2 requires centraldesktop/protobuf-php 0.5.* -> satisfiable by centraldesktop/protobuf-php[0.5.0, 0.5.1, 0.5.2].
    - centraldesktop/protobuf-php 0.5.2 requires symfony/console 2.* -> satisfiable by symfony/console[2.0.4, 2.0.5, 2.0.6, 2.0.7, 2.0.x-dev, 2.1.x-dev, 2.2.x-dev, 2.3.x-dev, 2.4.x-dev, 2.5.x-dev, 2.6.x-dev, 2.7.x-dev, 2.8.x-dev, v2.0.10, v2.0.12, v2.0.13, v2.0.14, v2.0.15, v2.0.16, v2.0.17, v2.0.18, v2.0.19, v2.0.20, v2.0.21, v2.0.22, v2.0.23, v2.0.24, v2.0.25, v2.0.9, v2.1.0, v2.1.1, v2.1.10, v2.1.11, v2.1.12, v2.1.13, v2.1.2, v2.1.3, v2.1.4, v2.1.5, v2.1.6, v2.1.7, v2.1.8, v2.1.9, v2.2.0, v2.2.1, v2.2.10, v2.2.11, v2.2.2, v2.2.3, v2.2.4, v2.2.5, v2.2.6, v2.2.7, v2.2.8, v2.2.9, v2.3.0, v2.3.1, v2.3.10, v2.3.11, v2.3.12, v2.3.13, v2.3.14, v2.3.15, v2.3.16, v2.3.17, v2.3.18, v2.3.19, v2.3.2, v2.3.20, v2.3.21, v2.3.22, v2.3.23, v2.3.24, v2.3.25, v2.3.26, v2.3.27, v2.3.28, v2.3.29, v2.3.3, v2.3.30, v2.3.31, v2.3.32, v2.3.33, v2.3.34, v2.3.35, v2.3.36, v2.3.37, v2.3.38, v2.3.39, v2.3.4, v2.3.40, v2.3.41, v2.3.42, v2.3.5, v2.3.6, v2.3.7, v2.3.8, v2.3.9, v2.4.0, v2.4.0-BETA1, v2.4.0-BETA2, v2.4.0-RC1, v2.4.1, v2.4.10, v2.4.2, v2.4.3, v2.4.4, v2.4.5, v2.4.6, v2.4.7, v2.4.8, v2.4.9, v2.5.0, v2.5.0-BETA1, v2.5.0-BETA2, v2.5.0-RC1, v2.5.1, v2.5.10, v2.5.11, v2.5.12, v2.5.2, v2.5.3, v2.5.4, v2.5.5, v2.5.6, v2.5.7, v2.5.8, v2.5.9, v2.6.0, v2.6.0-BETA1, v2.6.0-BETA2, v2.6.1, v2.6.10, v2.6.11, v2.6.12, v2.6.13, v2.6.2, v2.6.3, v2.6.4, v2.6.5, v2.6.6, v2.6.7, v2.6.8, v2.6.9, v2.7.0, v2.7.0-BETA1, v2.7.0-BETA2, v2.7.1, v2.7.10, v2.7.11, v2.7.12, v2.7.13, v2.7.14, v2.7.15, v2.7.16, v2.7.17, v2.7.18, v2.7.19, v2.7.2, v2.7.20, v2.7.21, v2.7.22, v2.7.23, v2.7.24, v2.7.25, v2.7.26, v2.7.27, v2.7.28, v2.7.29, v2.7.3, v2.7.30, v2.7.31, v2.7.32, v2.7.33, v2.7.34, v2.7.35, v2.7.36, v2.7.37, v2.7.38, v2.7.39, v2.7.4, v2.7.40, v2.7.41, v2.7.42, v2.7.43, v2.7.44, v2.7.45, v2.7.46, v2.7.47, v2.7.48, v2.7.49, v2.7.5, v2.7.50, v2.7.6, v2.7.7, v2.7.8, v2.7.9, v2.8.0, v2.8.0-BETA1, v2.8.1, v2.8.10, v2.8.11, v2.8.12, v2.8.13, v2.8.14, v2.8.15, v2.8.16, v2.8.17, v2.8.18, v2.8.19, v2.8.2, v2.8.20, v2.8.21, v2.8.22, v2.8.23, v2.8.24, v2.8.25, v2.8.26, v2.8.27, v2.8.28, v2.8.29, v2.8.3, v2.8.30, v2.8.31, v2.8.32, v2.8.33, v2.8.34, v2.8.35, v2.8.36, v2.8.37, v2.8.38, v2.8.39, v2.8.4, v2.8.40, v2.8.41, v2.8.42, v2.8.43, v2.8.44, v2.8.45, v2.8.46, v2.8.47, v2.8.48, v2.8.49, v2.8.5, v2.8.6, v2.8.7, v2.8.8, v2.8.9].
    - centraldesktop/protobuf-php 0.5.0 requires symfony/console 2.3.* -> satisfiable by symfony/console[2.3.x-dev, v2.3.0, v2.3.1, v2.3.10, v2.3.11, v2.3.12, v2.3.13, v2.3.14, v2.3.15, v2.3.16, v2.3.17, v2.3.18, v2.3.19, v2.3.2, v2.3.20, v2.3.21, v2.3.22, v2.3.23, v2.3.24, v2.3.25, v2.3.26, v2.3.27, v2.3.28, v2.3.29, v2.3.3, v2.3.30, v2.3.31, v2.3.32, v2.3.33, v2.3.34, v2.3.35, v2.3.36, v2.3.37, v2.3.38, v2.3.39, v2.3.4, v2.3.40, v2.3.41, v2.3.42, v2.3.5, v2.3.6, v2.3.7, v2.3.8, v2.3.9].
    - centraldesktop/protobuf-php 0.5.1 requires symfony/console 2.3.* -> satisfiable by symfony/console[2.3.x-dev, v2.3.0, v2.3.1, v2.3.10, v2.3.11, v2.3.12, v2.3.13, v2.3.14, v2.3.15, v2.3.16, v2.3.17, v2.3.18, v2.3.19, v2.3.2, v2.3.20, v2.3.21, v2.3.22, v2.3.23, v2.3.24, v2.3.25, v2.3.26, v2.3.27, v2.3.28, v2.3.29, v2.3.3, v2.3.30, v2.3.31, v2.3.32, v2.3.33, v2.3.34, v2.3.35, v2.3.36, v2.3.37, v2.3.38, v2.3.39, v2.3.4, v2.3.40, v2.3.41, v2.3.42, v2.3.5, v2.3.6, v2.3.7, v2.3.8, v2.3.9].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[2.0.4, v4.2.3].
    [...]
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.8.9, v4.2.3].
    - Installation request for symfony/console (locked at v4.2.3) -> satisfiable by symfony/console[v4.2.3].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

For me it looks like `centraldesktop/protobuf-php` is having a dependency conflict with Laravel. Both require `symfony/console`, protobuf0.5 need `2.*` while Laravel need `^4.1`.

This is my first issue with dependencies conflict and I don't know how to resolve it. I have tried adding `"symfony/console": "dev-master as 2.8"` but it dosen't work.

Does anyone have an idea on how I could get out of this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your assessment is correct. gtfs-realtime-bindings requires [centraldesktop/protobuf-php:0.5.*](https://packagist.org/packages/centraldesktop/protobuf-php#0.5.0) which has an unfortunate requirement on symfony/console. In later version they changed it to be a dev-requirement only (even then only console 3.x).

I don't think you can downgrade your symfony/console version safely. Instead what I would do is create a Pull Request to gtfs-realtime-bindings that bumps the minimum required version of centraldesktop/protobuf-php to `^1.0`. This might require other changes to the code as there might have been breaking changes between 0.5 to 1.0. Unfortunately [centraldesktop/Protobuf-PHP](https://github.com/centraldesktop/Protobuf-PHP) does not provide an upgrade guide, so you have to figure out if anything breaks via tests or code inspections in your IDE. Luckily gtfs-realtime-bindings is tested and seems to be rather small, so it should be manageable to do this upgrade even if you don't know all the internals. Plus, when you open a pull request that is work in progress maintainers will likely support you.

Another option would be to search for alternative implementations of the bindings or writing your own.

Comment: As a side note I just checked out google/gtfs-realtime-bindings-php and updated the dependency. The test still runs fine. I think upgrading the their dependency to a stable release is a good idea anyway, so I would recommend you create a pull request. Let me know if you need help doing it. If you don't want to do it yourself, let me know too and I will do it for you.

Comment: I'll try to make a pull request but I doubt it will be merged, repo haven't been updated for years. I'll keep you updated. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Yes, it seems the one class in it is auto-generated, but the composer.json should be unaffected by that. Good luck with that

Comment: I will probably build my own parser because I don't think updating Google's one will resolve this issue. I will have to update centraldesktop protobuf too!

Comment: Just curious is you ever ended up getting anywhere with this. If you did a fork of the repository etc?